# Joining two JSON objects in Node-RED

Tags: json, node-red

it's pretty simple. I have two flows in **Node-RED**, each of them carrying a **JSON object**.

As you can see here:

[image: Overview]
Originally on the first path, I created a new JSON object using the Template Node, which then was passed to the next node. Which works just fine.

Now, I have **two flows** from which I want to extract data.

Problem: The Template node only takes one input at a time. 
The result is two separated new JSON objects.

But, my target case is this combined JSON object:

```
{
    "followupEventInput": {
        "name": "{{response.prevIntent}}-{{response.utterances_tone.0.tones.0.tone_id}}",
        "parameters": {
            "tone_id": "{{response.utterances_tone.0.tones.0.tone_id}}"
        },
        "languageCode": "en-US"
  }
}
```

`response.utterances_tone.0.tones.0.tone_id` coming from the first flow.

`response.prevIntent` coming from the second flow.

It's not possible to pass the information I need through the first flow, because the information gets lost when passing the Tone Analyzer node.

I tried to work with Split & Join nodes but it just gets messy.

Have you any idea how this could be implemented smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `join` node.

This node has a number of modes, but you want the one that counts incoming messages before the outputting and object.

This will output a message with all the fields available, but you will probably need to use a `function` or `change` node to rearrange the structure to the one you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! Join node with counting incoming messages did do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to "chain" your two functions together into one flow -- it sounds like you tried to do this already, without success:

> It's not possible to pass the information I need through the first
>   flow, because the information gets lost when passing the Tone Analyzer
>   node.

So it seems that the Tone Analyzer node's output replaces the previous payload, instead of merging it together -- which is to be expected.

A solution is to put a `change` node after each function -- use it to Move: `msg.response` to another property, say `msg.response1` and `msg.response2`. Then you can use a `template` node to build the output structure you need. The "mustache" syntax you showed should work, if you pull the text from the response1 and response2 properties, like so:

```
{
    "followupEventInput": {
        "name": "{{response2.prevIntent}}-{{response1.utterances_tone.0.tones.0.tone_id}}",
        "parameters": {
            "tone_id": "{{response1.utterances_tone.0.tones.0.tone_id}}"
        },
        "languageCode": "en-US"
    }
}
```

Just make sure the set the `template` node to "Output as: Parsed JSON".
Oh, btw, you can probably replace your "Parse JSON" `function` node with the core `json` node, which does the parsing for you...

Comment: Thank you, too. I could solve the issue in another way.